# Apache не видит папку имя которой начинается с точки

Tags: apache

Apache не даёт доступ к папке имя которой начинается с точки, и не показывает её в браузере. Как это решить?

Comment: Подробнее, пожалуйста. Как вы смотрите папку (запрос - покажите), операционка, права.

Comment: Если посмотреть папку без сервера, на прямую из windows через chrome, то всё видно, права есть. Если же при запущенном сервере, то все другие папки открываются(средством просмотра файлов chrome), а эта папка (с названием .default) - нет. И если пытаешься подключить из неё файлы (css, js, img) то 403, доступ запрещён. Но сервер эту папку видит, просто доступ не даёт. Операционная система - Windpows 10. Openserver. Права есть у всех user'ов на просмотр папки.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте стереть из конфигов апача, где:

> LocationMatch "/.(?!well-known)"

Нашел инфу на https://toster.ru/q/314438

Comment: Дмитрий, похоже что предложенное Вами решение, верное. Просто несколько дней назад я понял, что установленный у меня openserver имеет  проблемы с чтением папок, начинающихся с точки. Установил другой локальный сервер, xampp. Проблема решилась.

Answer (score 0):

Если имя файла в Linux начинается с точки, то файл - скрытый. Apache изначально пришел из linux, поэтому у него и такое поведение.

Правильное решение: поменяйте в соглашении об именовании файлов точку на _ например и переименуйте файлы.

Comment: Спасибо. Но в bitrix, это не работает. Там по умолчанию папка с точкой. Я пришёл к выводу, что openserver плохо читает именно такие папки. Установил другой локальный сервер, xampp. Проблема решилась.

Comment: "По умолчанию" как правило означает что эту опцию можно изменить.

Answer (score 0):

Если конфиг OpenServer Apache+nginx - в конфиге nginx закомментируйте эту строку:

```
if ($uri ~* /\.(?!well-known)) {
    return 404;
}
```